What makes Phi Silica "NPU-tuned"? Is it just that it runs on a neural processing unit (NPU), or something else?
I read on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/apis/phi-silica:

Use the Windows App SDK to connect your Windows app to on-device language models, including Phi Silica, our most powerful NPU-tuned local language model yet.

What makes Phi Silica "NPU-tuned"? Is it just that it runs on a neural processing unit (NPU), or something else?
